# Combine data of two or more iPhones

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, backup, data-synchronization

I have **multiples iOS devices** - a 64 GB iPhone 6 Plus, a 128 GB iPhone 6 and a 128 iPhone 6 Plus.
I want to *combine all the data* on all these phones into a *single iPhone*.

By data, i mean **Photos, Mail, Contacts, Calendars, Reminders, Notes, Wallet, iBooks**. I have **iCloud Sync** turned **ON**, but the *data exceeds 5 GB* (obviously), so I want to know if there is a way of doing so *without the Cloud* or via the *Internet*. Maybe **iTunes** can help me somehow. I regularly **backup** my Photos to Microsoft OneDrive and Google Photos, but i doubt if they are the originals as i had captured. Especially, the panorama, hyperlapses and slowmotion videos.

I am also willing to buy a *new 256 GB iPhone 7/Plus* (if disk space is an issue), but i would prefer to combine the data into an existing device, assuming **free space is available** or not an issue, how can i achieve that goal?

Comment: Don't jailbreak them all, that's a terrible idea. Do you sync your phones with a Mac or a PC?

Comment: i use both/either OSs

Comment: I'd suggest that you sync all the phones you have to one machine (preferably the Mac) and then sync the new phone with that machine, therefore it will have a complete collection of your data and then it'll just add all that data to the one device. It should be pretty straight forward, no need to jailbreak it or anything like what other joker was cracking on about